# Python: Passing variables into imported function vs keeping within the same module for loops and dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, memory-management

I'm sure there is a doc answering this exact question somewhere but I'm not sure what to google exactly

Scenario:

I have a decision tree that I need to iterate over a large dictionary and based on certain conditions needs to fetch variables from various input dictionaries. I know if I keep all these in the same module I can access the global variable in my function but if I split these into separate modules I'd have to pass in all the input dictionaries.

Question 1)

In the second case does this duplicate memory or are the passed in variables just a pointer to a position in memory.

Question 2)

For editing and creating new keys within a dictionary is there a way to amend a dictionary without having to reassign it.

Many thanks

**Current Situation:**

```
input_dict = 
    {'A': 1, 'B': 2}

large_dictionary= 
    {1 : { 'Name': 'John', 'Age': 30},
    ....
    1000 : { 'Name': 'Sam', 'Age': 20}}

def function_1():
    data['variable_to_create'] = input_dict['A']

for key,data in large_dictionary.items():
    ...
    Some large decision tree
    ...
    function_1()
```

**Proposed Situation:**

Module

```
def function_1(data, input_dict):
    data['variable_to_create'] = input_dict['A']
    return data
```

Code

```
from new_module import function_1

input_dict = 
    {'A': 1, 'B': 2}

large_dictionary= 
    {1 : { 'Name': 'John', 'Age': 30},
    ....
    1000 : { 'Name': 'Sam', 'Age': 20}}

for key,data in large_dictionary.items():
    ...
    Some large decision tree
    ...
    data = function_1(data, input_dict)
```

Comment: Passing the dictionary to `function_1` doesn't copy the data, it passes a reference. The called function can do anything it likes with the reference: amend the dictionary, reassign it, clear it, delete it.

Comment: So if I change the last bit of the Proposed Situation code to: function_1(data, input_dict) instead of data = function_1(data, input_dict)  Would it perform as the Current Situation??

Comment: As far as I can see, yes.